# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.api.retrofit.AuthenticationInterceptor$intercept$1

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

I recently added retrofit2 to my app. It works well on a Nexus 6P running Android 8.0, but when testing on an older OnePlus One, running Android 6.0.1, I ran into an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.api.retrofit.AuthenticationInterceptor$intercept$1
    at com.example.api.retrofit.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.kt:21)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
    at com.example.fragment.xx.XXFragment$onViewCreated$2.getItemsForConstraint(XXFragment.kt:53)
    at com.example.view.MyAutoCompleteTextView$Adapter$getFilter$1.performFiltering(MyAutoCompleteTextView.kt:114)
    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is my code:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        okhttpVersion = '3.8.0'
        retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    }
...
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpVersion"
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion") {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
```

Building the service:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(new AuthenticationInterceptor(ctx))
        .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
        .build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(HOST + VERSION + "/")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(new EnvelopingConverter())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
retrofitService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
```

The interceptor:

```
import android.content.Context
import com.example.api.Api
import com.example.controller.AuthManager
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response

class AuthenticationInterceptor(val context: Context) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response? {
        var request = chain?.request()
        val headers = AuthManager.getAuthHeaders(context)

        if (request != null) {
            val requestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
            requestBuilder.addHeader(Api.HEADER_ACCEPT, Api.HEADER_APP_JSON)

            headers.forEach { key, value ->  // this is line 21
                requestBuilder.addHeader(key, value)
            }

            request = requestBuilder.build()
        }

        return chain?.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue might be? Anyone has any ideas?

## UPDATE:

Wrote the interceptor in java and it seems to work. Why? I would really want to stick to Kotlin for this project.

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private Context context;

    public AuthInterceptor(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Map<String, String> headers = AuthManager.getAuthHeaders(context);
        if (request != null) {
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();
            requestBuilder.addHeader(Api.HEADER_ACCEPT, Api.HEADER_APP_JSON);
            for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
                requestBuilder.addHeader(key, headers.get(key));
            }
            request = requestBuilder.build();
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: invalidate cache and restart may help.

Comment: are you using proguard ?

Comment: no, i'm not using proguard

Comment: So, when I wrote the interceptor in java, it worked. Why doesn't it work with Kotlin?

Comment: should be working in kotlin. i have done using interceptor in kotlin project. look here https://github.com/radityagumay/android-clean-architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of hours of debugging, I figured out what was going on:

In my gradle file I also had `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"`

Because of this, it allowed me to use the following code:

```
headers.forEach { key, value ->  // this is line 21
    requestBuilder.addHeader(key, value)
}
```

When decompiling and looking at the java code, this will look like this:

```
e.forEach((BiConsumer)(new BiConsumer() {
           // $FF: synthetic method
           // $FF: bridge method
           public void accept(Object var1, Object var2) {
              this.accept((String)var1, (String)var2);
           }
           public final void accept(String key, String value) {
              requestBuilder.addHeader(key, value);
           }
        }));
```

The problem here is that the class [BiConsumer was **added in API level 24**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html).
That's why it worked on Android 8.0(API level 26) and it didn't work on Android 6.0.1(API level 23).

So, I ended up using a regular for loop instead of the forEach I went for initially.

The main problem here is the exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.api.retrofit.AuthenticationInterceptor$intercept$1`. If it would have said `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.function.BiConsumer`, I think it would have been much easier to debug.

Comment: But it is not a biconsumer, it is an anonymous subclass of it

Comment: in the decompiled code, the import looks like this: `import java.util.function.BiConsumer;`

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable Instant Run.

1 2 3

Comment: Hm. Only difference I noticed in interceptor is nullable result. Try change to 
`override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {`